# Eclipse CDT spell-check in XML (non-C++) files

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, spell-checking

In Eclipse Oxygen with CDT I can configure spell checking for most file types under

```
Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Spelling
```

However for XML files, which are apparently opened in the "Structured Text Editor", I can not find such an option.

Is this hidden somewhere or covered by a good plug-in?

---

**Update**

The [user guide mentions](http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.sse.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftsrcedt010.html) spell-checking for "Structured Text Editor", but that does not match the actual UI; neither "Window > Preferences > Spell Check" exists as described nor "Edit > Spell Check":

[image: Window > Preferences > Spell Check]
[image: Edit > Spell Check]

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour in the Oxygen C/C++ package. On the other hand spell checking works in the XML Editor in the Oxygen Java EE package. (Both Windows 64-bit.)

Comment: @tkruse  I had to explicitly open the file using "Open with" > "XML Editor" in order to see the tabs. But neither in "Source" nor "Design" mode do I see any spell checking.

Comment: @tkruse Spell-checking in any kind of view would work, as long as no hack (such as renaming to .xml.cpp) is required.  And no, txt files are not checked either, even though "Preferences > General > Editors > Spelling" is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
Seems to be a known bug / feature request:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=185695
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=521658

Possibly installing Java tooling on top would fix.

NOT HELPING:

The eclipse help has an article on this:
http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.sse.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftsrcedt010.html

Also Eclipse should have an "Open With" context menu entry by which you could open as a text file, and have spell check.

Comment: I was aware of that page, but should probably have linked to it in the question.  What's written there does however not work (at least in CDT). I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: Installing the "Eclipse Java Development Tools" did indeed the trick!